# strtotime() returns different Unix timestamp in different timezones for string "now"

Tags: php

```
php > echo strtotime("now America/New_York")."\n";
1376459035 // -> 2013-08-14 05:43:55 - Wrong

php > echo strtotime("now UTC")."\n";
1376444635 // -> 2013-08-14 01:43:55 - OK

php > echo time()."\n";
1376444635 // -> 2013-08-14 01:43:55 - OK
```

Can anyone explain?

Is this some PHP's invention – timezone-"corrected" unix timestamps?

// edit:

I realize it makes no sense to even specify the timezone with "now". It does, however, with other relative times, e.g. "tomorrow midnight". There, depending on the timezone, "tomorrow" could be a day further away, depending on whether the timezone is over midnight already. The behavior is equally weird, just a bit harder to explain.

Comment: Close for "too broad" .. err what? How could it be more specific?

Comment: Having trawled the PHP documentation I can't find your time format documented. Either I've missed it (please post a  link), or you've hit on an undocumented feature.

Comment: This is perfectly normal.

Comment: @MikeW See here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php (I guess with "now" and "tz" symbols being in a different sections and the docs saying "In most cases formats from different sections can be used in the same date/time string", it's hard to be sure whether this is supported or not. It doesn't seem to return an error, at least.)

Answer (score 0):

As explained on [Unix time wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), Unix Epoch is always in UTC. Thats why outputs from

```
echo strtotime("now UTC");
echo time();
```

are the same. According [this info](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=179) New York time zone is `UTC -5 hours`. With current daylight saving time +1 now it equally `UTC -4 hours`. That's why you got result `2013-08-14 05:43:55` (4 hours diff).

Comment: This is a bit confusion because i woould expect that, using strtotime("now") alone would use the system timezone to do the calculation, but if i changed the default timezone, it would use that timezone, not the system one...

Answer (score 0):

you are using 
`strtotime("now America/New_York")` thats why it is showing unix timestamp in different timezone for string.

**use this:**

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```